# How to use 'print' macro with an unknown argument

Tags: c

This code doesn't work but when I put `print(7)` this works fine:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define print(i) printf("%"#i"c",ch);

int main(void) 
{
    char ch ='*';
    int N;
    scanf("%d",&N);

    if (N%2 == 0)
    {
            print(N); // print(7);
    }
    else
    {

    }
}
```

Here is the compilation output

```
 gcc draw.c -o draw
 draw.c: In function ‘main’:
 draw.c:11: warning: unknown conversion type character ‘N’ in format
```

How can I get the code to work for a user inserted input. Please help.

Comment: Why are you trying to use a macro for this?

Comment: I like to try my ideas. This time I want to implement a x for all the numbers that the user inputs .What I mean is the * will be shifted to the right by the number user inputs.

Comment: Are you aware that macro replacement takes places even before the real compilation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the `#` operator is part of the preprocessor. It doesn't understand run-time values.

The `printf` function recognizes a `*` syntax that tells it to accept an `int` argument that specifies a field width, rather than having the width as a constant in the format string.

For example, this function could replace your macro. Note that I've made `ch` a parameter; I think it's much clearer that way.

```
int print(int n, char ch) {
    return printf("%*c", n, ch);
}
```

Personally, I probably wouldn't bother with either a function or a macro for this; I'd just call `printf` directly:

```
printf("%*c", n, '*');
```